# Cómo llamar varias funciones en un mismo onclick

Tags: javascript, html, css

Necesito activar varios elementos en un onclick pero sucede que solo me sirve cuando pongo dos funciones ejemplo:

```
<a onclick='funcion1();funcion2(); de aqui en adelante no funciona'></a>
```

pero cuando quiero poner más no funciona lo que estoy llamando, quiero saber si hay posibilidad de hacerlo funcionar o si hay otra manera de hacerlo.

Comment: ¿y si haces una funcionTodos(); que dentro mande a llamar a funcion1, 2, ...N?

Comment: Comparto la opinión de @shop350.

Comment: y cómo lo hago?

Comment: funcionGeneral() { funcion1(); funcion2(); funcion3(); } pero eso lo haces en el javascript no en el html

Comment: Tú problema esta en otro lado, el código que muestras en el ejemplo es totalmente válido

Comment: Esa línea de código está bien, pero seguramente `funcion2()` provoque un error en tiempo de ejecución o contenga una sentencia `return`, impidiendo que `funcion3()` sea ejecutado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Como ha dicho @shop350, llama a la función todos desde el html.
Dentro de la función `todos()`, llama a las demás funciones.
Te añado el código.

```js
function todos(){
    funcion1();
    funcion2();
    funcion3();
    funcion4();
}

function funcion1(){
    console.log("funcion uno");
}
function funcion2(){
    console.log("funcion dos");
}
function funcion3(){
    console.log("funcion tres");
}
function funcion4(){
    console.log("funcion cuatro");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>
<body>
<a onclick='todos()'></a>
</body>

</html>
```