# Dos funciones, SELECT ,Un OnClick

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, onclick

si me pueden por fa colaborar con lo siguiente:

Tengo un formulario con 3 select:
SELECT1: Procesos,
SELECT2: categorías,
SELECT3: subprocesos

La información que se carga en los select SELECT2 y SELECT3, dependen de lo escogido en el SELECT1. Sin embargo no he logrado hacer que se carguen ambos select al mismo tiempo, solo me carga uno. Intenté hacer lo de [esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/231884/c%C3%B3mo-llamar-varias-funciones-en-un-mismo-onclick#) respuesta, pero no funciona. Este es mi .js:

```
function subcategory(){

    let proces = $('#process').val()
    console.log(proces);
    $.ajax({
      url: 'assets/php_jquery/jquerysub.php',
      data: {proces},
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (response) {
        if(!response.error) {
          let conts = JSON.parse(response);
          console.log(response)
          let template = '';
          conts.forEach(cont => {
            template += `
            <option class="option" value="${cont.idsub}">${cont.title}</option> 
            `;
          });
          $('.option').remove();
          $('.sub1').html(template);
        }
      } 
    })

}

function category(){

    let proces = $('#process').val()
    console.log(proces);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'assets/php_jquery/jquery.php',
        data: {proces},
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (response) {
          if(!response.error) {
            let conts = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response)
            let template = '';
            conts.forEach(cont => {
              template += `
              <option class="option" value="${cont.idprocess}">${cont.title}</option> 
              `;
            });
            $('.option').remove();
            $('.category1').html(template);
          }
        } 
    })

}

$('#process').click(function(){
  
   category();
   subcategory();

    
})
```

Ayuda por favor, gracias,

Answer (score 4):

Para que cada vez que se cambia la opción seleccionada en el `<select id="process">` se actualicen los datos en los otros dos `select`, necesitas suscribir una función al evento `change`.

#### Ejemplo:

```
$('#process').on('change', function() {
   category();
   subcategory();
});
```

---

Referencias:

- [Evento `change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)
- [jQuery.on](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 0):

Lo pude resolver cambiando el class="option" de una de las funciones:

```
conts.forEach(cont => {
            template += `
            <option class="option1" value="${cont.idsub}">${cont.title}</option> 
            `;
          });
          $('.option1').remove();
          $('.sub1').html(template);
```